# GetOrgChart: Nodes whose parent haven't been defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, orgchart

I'm using the [GetOrgChart JQuery plugin](http://www.getorgchart.com/) and running into a JavaScript error of:

> Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property '_ap' of null

I was able to determine that this is occurring in the case from my dataset where a user occurs earlier in the list than their manager does.  My hierarchy is based around NTLogins, so the NTLogin of a given user is the `id` and the `parentId` is their manager's NTLogin.

```
$("#people").getOrgChart({
    primaryColumns: ["Name"],
    dataSource: [{
        id: "bobeans125",
        parentId: null,
        Name: "Bob Beans"
        }, {
        id: "franklin884",
        parentId: "tdawl756",
        Name: "Frank Lin"
        }, {
        id: "tdawl756",
        parentId: "bobeans125",
        Name: "Tim Dawl"
        }]
});
```

[JSFIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chuckgross/kyAeV/)

I have no good way that I can think of to order the data so that this doesn't occur other than finding all of the many root nodes and drilling down into the hierarchy manually so that the dataset being sent to GetOrgChart is ordered.  However, the assumption of not having to do so was the primary driver for choosing GetOrgChart.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just recursively walking the tree and building the object in the right order. I was able to get it to load without error, however, the tree is too large to be displayed and requires being zoomed out too far to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Id : and ParentId: is integer value but you gave string value so your output is Error: Cannot read property '_ap' of null.

```
Correct Example:
$("#people").getOrgChart({
primaryColumns: ["Name"],
dataSource: [{
    id: 1,
    parentId: null,
    Name: "Bob Beans"
    }, {
    id: 2,
    parentId: 1,
    Name: "Frank Lin"
    }, {
    id: "3",        
    parentId: "1",
    Name: "Tim Dawl"
    }]
 });
```